# Linux rootfs on iSCSI: Cannot remount read-write

Tags: linux, ext4, root-filesystem, readonly, iscsi

I have a Linux server with an ext4 rootfs on iSCSI.

The iSCSI server rebooted and this interrupted the communication, which is usually not a big deal because the server is quick to restart.

However, when the iSCSI server takes too long, the client server will switch the rootfs to read-only.

The problem is that, once it becomes read-only, I can't find a way to make it read-write again. It keeps telling me the device is read-only (which is not the case).

I tried and checked the following:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
mount: /: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected.

# cat /sys/block/sda/ro 
0
# cat /sys/block/sda/sda1/ro 
0

# hdparm -r /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
# hdparm -r /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

Is there any way to fix this issue without rebooting the server?

#### Notes

I have other iSCSI devices that are configured to use multipath, but they are not mounted (they are passed to VMs).

The rootfs device is not configured to use multipath because its iSCSI target is loaded from initramfs.

The VMs running on the other iSCSI devices are not affected by this issue: they just get frozen during the interruption and get back to work when everything is back online.
And they continue to work fine even with read-only rootfs.